# PGFPLOTS with symbolic x coords that include blank character and the data comes from a .txt file

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying for half a day now to create a barchart with `PGFPLOTS` what normaly works very well.
But now I need to use names in the `symbolic x coords` that include blank characters like "2m C". This causes an error when the data is read from the txt file.

It is my first time writing here, so i hope i did all the formats right ;-)

Thank you for your help!

Belowe my code and data

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
xlabel= Cases,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 52,
ybar=2,
symbolic x coords={Chips,2m C,External recycling,Sawdust,4m Ds,3m Ds,2m Ds,4m C,3m C,Offcuts,Bark extern,Residues,Bark internal,CB Dh,CB C,CB Ds,Slabs,Hardwood,Complaint},]

\addplot[draw=none] table[y index=1 {result_assortment.txt};
\addplot[draw=none] table[y index=2] {result_assortment.txt};


\legend{Loaded Runs, Empty Runs}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

And the Data

```
FF                  Case A      Final
Chips               39245.77    37038.03
2m C                5490.63     5490.63
External recycling  2658.83     1436.96
Sawdust             4075.6      3834.34
4m Ds               5278.69     5456.15
3m Ds               7256.12     7136.97
2m Ds               1263.25     997.2
4m C                44248.02    25461.51
3m C                69276.62    20896.06
Offcuts             12709.9     12080.03
Bark extern         547         285.71
Residues            1337.05     1091.96
Bark internal       12276.22    0
CB Dh               9089.01     7886.36
CB C                15884.24    12338.54
CB Ds               4694.89     2506.33
Slabs               10553.13    6787.87
Hardwood            761.76      225.35
Complaint           1023.09     1035.27
```

Comment: I assume that you're using tabs as the column separators in your `result_assortment.txt` file? In that case, you should use `\addplot[draw=none] table[col sep=tab, y index=1] {result_assortment.txt};`, otherwise PGFPlots tries to use the spaces as column separators.

Comment: Did the trick of Jake help you to solve he question or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have been solved by Jake's comment (?).